# Classical philosophical texts on aesthetics

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics

What are the best (according to most philosophers) classical philosophical texts on aesthetics?

I have found several ones on the Internet, but I don't know which one to start with first.

Comment: 'Best' is always a problematic attribute. But if you do not know where to start at all, secondary literature such as the [Oxford Handbook](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199279456.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199279456) are sometimes helpful, as they offer summaries and give more or less authoritative qualifications of 'most influential' or 'historically relevant'.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, I am only interested in classical texts.

Comment: The *Critique of Judgement* by Immanuel Kant (1795) will definitely be considered as 'classical'. Regarding older texts, you should be aware of the fact that virtue (ethics) and aesthetics used to be even more closely intertwined than for Kant.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, I am not ready for Kant's works yet. Other suggestions, perhaps?

Comment: aesthetics is a hard topic in philosophy (at least to do well). It's going to be hard to find a classical text that is simultaneously accessible and well regarded. A good secondary (contemporary) source to get you started: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/beauty/

Comment: It might help if you can say something about the kind of art you're interested in for example: music, poetry, dance, the visual arts or drama

Comment: You could try Kandinskys *The Spiritual in Art*; he's a visual artist whose famous for being the first to move to pure abstraction in art without a figurative element; it's more in the form of a polemic though, it's short and readable though; another classic text is Bergers *Ways of Seeing*.

Comment: i would go for @PhilipKlöcking advice instead of the stanford pages, which read more like an opinion piece than a summary, at least sometimes

Answer (score 3):

The "best" according to me...

**Aristotle** *Poetics*

**Longinus** *On the Sublime*

**Immanuel Kant** *Critique_of_Judgment*

**Hegel** *Lectures_on_Aesthetics*

**Schiller** *On the Aesthetic Education of Man*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetics_(Aristotle)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectures_on_Aesthetics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique_of_Judgment

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sublime

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Schiller#Aesthetic_Letters

Answer (score 0):

you could try something from danto: an essay like *the art world*, or a book like *after the end of art*. you would get quite a lot out of them. 
or something by richard wollheim - *art and its objects*. these are quite highly regarded art critics who also had a rigorous philosophical training.